# Move to the new row in datagridview using Enter Key in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row, keypress

This is my code for pressing Enter Key and moving to the next cell:

```
Private Sub dvFromAlloc_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dvFromAlloc.CellEndEdit
    SendKeys.Send("{up}")
    SendKeys.Send("{right}")
End Sub

Private Sub dvFromAlloc_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles dvFromAlloc.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        SendKeys.Send("{up}")
        SendKeys.Send("{right}")
    End If
End Sub
```

This is perfectly working, now what I want is if the user is in the last column, how can I move the cell to the first column of the second row?

Thank you.

Comment: @matzone: Hi sir, can you explain how can I use selectedcells, I cannot understand you comment clearly, Thank you for the help

Comment: Sorry, it' corrected .. I mean dgv.CurrentCell .. you try to set currentrow +1 and column = 0 ..

Comment: @matzone: in what part I will set the currentrow+ 1 should i put it both in the cellend edit and keydown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in your `KeyDown` event ..

```
Private Sub dvFromAlloc_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles dvFromAlloc.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        dvFromAlloc.CurrentCell = dvFromAlloc.Rows(dvFromAlloc.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1).Cells(0)
        dtg.Rows(i).Cells(aColumn(x))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle Enter Key at Datagridview in win forms..

bool notlastColumn = true;

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {
        int icolumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int irow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int i = irow;
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (icolumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
            {

                //dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                if (notlastColumn == true  )
                {
                   dataGridView1.CurrentCell= dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                }
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, irow + 1];

            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[icolumn + 1, irow];
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```